# PHP - file upload will not move file to directory

Tags: php, file-upload

the file upload script is below...the storing of the file name in the DB is working fine, but the file is not being moved to the proper directory. the "Avatars" file is located in the "/httpdocs/" directory. I have set the permissions to "777".

```
<?php
require('dbconfig.php');

//generate a random string
function generateRandomString($length = 40) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$customname = generateRandomString();

$newimagename = "$customname." . pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    header ('Location: /dashboard.php?filetype=invalid');
    exit();
    }
  else
    {
    //echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    //echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    //echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    //echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      //echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "avatars/" . $newimagename);
      //echo "Stored in: " . "profile_videos/" . $newimagename;

        $storedtoken = $_COOKIE['login_token'];
        $mysqlicon = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
        //identify the user by comparing tokens
        $find_user_id = mysqli_query($mysqlicon, "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE token='$storedtoken'");

        //grab the user's UUID
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($find_user_id)) {
            $uuid = $row['userID'];
            mysqli_query($mysqlicon, "UPDATE families SET avatarURL='avatars/$newimagename' where husbandID='$uuid' OR wifeID='$uuid'");
            mysqli_close($mysqlicon);
        }

      header ('Location: /dashboard.php');

      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  header ('Location: /dashboard.php?profile-video-upload=invalid');
  mysqli_close($mysqlicon);
  exit();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Check your server logs. What messages do you see there?

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection.